# JavaScript "x in obj": obj.x is undefined?

Tags: javascript, syntax, for-in-loop

The following code :

```
var obj = {uname:"OdO", age:"22"};  
alert(obj.uname);
```

results in:

```
OdO
```

Now, using the same concept in a `for..in` statement :

```
for (x in obj) {
    document.write(obj.x+"<br>");
}
```

I expected it to print the following:

```
OdO  
22
```

but it prints :

```
undefined  
undefined
```

And to achieve printing looping in the elements, it should be written as an array elements like this:

```
for (x in obj) {
    document.write(obj[x]+"<br>");
}
```

Then, why the first syntax doesn't work, however it works out of the `for..in` statement ?

Comment: The issue is `obj.x` (`x` is an identifier used as a property name) vs. `obj[x]` (`x` is an *expression which is evaluated* and then used as the property name) which has been covered already elsewhere. It has *nothing* to do with the `for...in`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `obj.x`, this literally looks for a property named "x" in `obj` — just like `obj.size` would look for a property named "size". `x` is not defined for your objects, so it comes out as nothing. The correct way of writing it — `obj[x]` — uses the *variable* `x` to look up a property in the object. The bracket syntax uses the value inside the brackets to look up the property, while the dot syntax turns the property name into a string. So these two are equivalent:

```
obj.x
obj["x"]
```

So when you write `x` after `obj.`, it converts that `x` into a string — it's not a variable anymore.

Comment: by the same concept, why this `obj[x]` doesn't look for a key `x`?..why the same object/structure is treated differently?

Comment: Wouldn't `obj[x]` (in the first iteration) look for `obj['OdO']`? Wouldn't that be `undefined` as well, since it should be `obj['uname']`? I'm confused ><

Comment: @Shredder: Unless I misunderstand your question, no. The for-loop enumerates the keys, while '0d0` is a value — so it would look up `obj['uname']`.

Comment: Ooh, my mistake, I thought it enumerated values

Comment: @OdO: I updated my answer. Basically, `obj.x` doesn't use your variable `x` at all, while the bracket syntax does.

Comment: then, each object has an array with the same name containing its properties? or; the object itself can be treated as an array?, i.e : `obj[x]` is the same object I declared in the code, or it is an auto generated array with the same name as the object?

Comment: @OdO: Arrays don't really have anything to do with it. I know in some languages `[]` is just for array lookups, but JavaScript is not one of those languages. In JavaScript, `[]` is the operator for looking up a property in an object. Arrays are a kind of object, so you do use brackets with them too, but there aren't any arrays in the example we're looking at here. So yes, the `obj` in `obj[x]` is the same one as elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4):

The bracket syntax is used to receive a property whose name is the expression (expression can be a literal, a variable or something more complex):

```
var x = "a";
{a:0, b:1}[x] == 0;
```

The dot syntax is used to receive the property with exactly that name:

```
({a:0, x:1}).x == 1;
```

In your for-in-loop, the variable `x` holds the property name. You are trying to acess the property named `"x"`, which is not defined.

Comment: then, an object can be treated as an array?

Comment: What do you mean? A javascript Object is like an associative array, that's true, but should not be interchanged with an javascript Array - they have different purposes.

Comment: then having an object named `ob` means I must not declare an array with the same name `ob` ?

Comment: A variable named "ob" may either hold a Object or an Array instance. Both structures store a set of items, indexed either by string or numeric keys. Properties of different objects can have the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Use the bracket form (`obj[x]`) when the property name is stored in a variable named "x" and the attribute form (`obj.x`) when the property name is *literally* "x".

For example:

```javascript
var o = {foo:1};
o.foo; // => 1
var x = 'foo';
o[x]; // => 1, since x='foo' and has a property named "foo".
o.x; // => undefined, since "o" has no property named "x".
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for(var x in obj){
    console.log(obj[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
var obj = {uname:"OdO", age:"22"};  

for (x in obj) {
    document.write(obj[x.toString()] + "<br>");
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zA8HB/